# Pip install not able to install any packages on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

When trying to run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get the output:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd411c5b730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))': /simple/mypy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd411c4f9d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))': /simple/mypy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd411c4f130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))': /simple/mypy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd411c4f160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))': /simple/mypy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd411c4f1c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))': /simple/mypy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypy==0.790 (from -r requirements_dev.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mypy==0.790 (from -r requirements_dev.txt (line 1))
```

I am running: Ubuntu 20.04

Versions: Python 3.8.5, pip 20.0.2

Not behind a proxy. Using a virtualenv but pip install does not work outside of the virtualenv either.

I have tried reinstalling pip a couple of times and have an alias on pip3 which is why pip should work. I have also tried upgrading pip but always get that I am already up to date in the output.

Comment: You don't have a proxy but your configuration seem to think otherwise. If you really don't have a proxy you have to verify config file and environment variables for proxy settings and remove them. See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_config/, https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration